# How to send text message when they also what imessage

Tags: messages, sms, text

My brother has a Windows Phone, and an iPad. Whenever I try to text him, it sends him an iMessage to his iPad, not a text message. Since he does not always have his iPad with him, he doesn't get my texts most of the time.

Is there a way to choose when a message is sent via iMessage, or via SMS?

Answer (score 1):

If you press and hold on the iMessage it will let you choose Send as Text Message. If you do this enough it will automatically start to send as a text message.

Also tell your brother to visit https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage to deregister his iMessage so this doesnt happen with anyone else.